# replace some text in a existing PDF using PDFBOX

Tags: pdfbox

To achieve this my approach is:-

1) first I will get the coordinates (X,Y) of the word which I have to replace

2)And then re-write on that word in Append mode.

Now, the problem is when I manually putting the coordinates after getting the coordinates separately. I am getting the appended file however, the text is appended at some other location

Last coordinate of char is:- s [(X=119.27521,Y=82.579956) height=5.52 width=4.3166428]

and I am writing through this code:-

contentStream.newLineAtOffset((float) 119.27521, (float) 82.579956);

Comment: That sounds like you get the coordinates in a different coordinate system than the one in which the replacement is drawn.

Comment: What MKL means is that a PDF can have up-to 5 different coordinate systems. (MediaBox, CropBox, BleedBox, TrimBox, ArtBox). Depending on which coordinates you get and where you draw it results might differ. (https://www.prepressure.com/pdf/basics/page-boxes)

Comment: So, How can I get coordinates from, one coordinate System using PDFBOX